# ASP.NET Core 6 : get Windows user

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am having a devil of a time getting a simple Windows Domain User in my view in an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project. Looking in Google, I see a lot of people having the same question but very few suggestions past a full auth system.

I was just hoping to turn on Windows auth and get a username, no need for any other functions then to just display a name in the view.

In the past I have used:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

I have this in my `launchSettings.json`:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

I did also added this code to `Program.cs`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Is there no way to just grab the windows user for a display value in ASP.NET Core 6

Comment: Are you using IIS, IIS Express, or Kestrel? Did you have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: I did look at that documentation but was hoping I didnt need to implement a full auth system in order to get a username in the view, thank you for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion,you should have authentication to get `UserName`,you need to Enable Windows Authentication.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

launchSettings.json:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
}
```

Controller:

```
string UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more details,please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

If you do not need to automaticaly login the user with Windows Authentication, and you have already a custom login Controller to do that,you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356583/asp-net-core-get-user-windows-username).

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I did try the link you added before asking for help here. I added to my controler: string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            string userNameAuth = (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).ToString(); but both appear to be null values. Im sure im doign something incorrect but not sure what there. I was looking at adding the above to my project, NegotiateDefaults appears red. I assume i need to set that? im looking into what that value is, thank you for the direction.

Comment: I added the NuGet package and your solution worked out. I can capture users with HttpContext.User.Identity.Name Thank you for your help

Comment: The above worked well local but when i pushed to azure i get the error, "The Negotiate Authentication handler cannot be used on a server that directly supports Windows Authentication. Enable Windows Authentication for the server and the Negotiate Authentication handler will defer to it."  Have you seen this before?

Comment: I have the same issue. When I publish to Azure, I get the error. Have you found the solution for this?