# ASP.NET Core web app (Model-View-Controller) - cannot get user from HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, httpcontext

I've been working on rebuilding an old ASP.NET webforms app built back in 2010 from scratch. I'm using the ASP.NET Core web app (Model-View-Controller) project template (C#) with Visual Studio 2022 Professional.

No matter what articles I follow, I cannot get to the `HttpContext.User.Name` value. Essentially attempting to recreate the old ASP.NET functionality of obtaining the user name of the user who connected to the site using Windows authentication.

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

both always return null.

I've gone through training materials, every article I can find, and I'm very much missing something. Any pointers on this would be very much appreciated.

`launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:38899",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5105",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`HomeController` - all defaults from the project creation:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string user = "";
    user = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    return View();
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using WebApplication1.Controllers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".TestSession";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; //disallows cookie access via client side script
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Add Authentication to your app in `program.cs`. Here's a related post: [asp-net-6-get-windows-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692474/asp-net-6-get-windows-user), By the way, it may help to clarify what version of asp.net-core you are using

Comment: Sorry, Asp.Net 7.0.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for updating. You should be able to use the example in the answer in my link above.

Comment: omg.  Add that as an answer and I'll mark it as such.  That is EXACTLY what I've needed and been missing.  thank you SO MUCH!  I was pushing meltdown over this simple task. lol.  Thank you!

All of the garbage I've found about adding Identity Nugets, passing IHttpContextAccessor's to controllers, Httpcontext.User.FindFirst(blahblahblah) hasn't worked at all.  You literally saved me from a mental breakdown.  X-D

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm going to vote to close as this is a duplicate. But I'm only doing that to follow SO guidelines, nothing against your question.

Comment: Just FYI, I was able to get a Windows user, all be it at the process usage level without any of this solution.  This was very specific to httpcontext usage which was a real pain to narrow down this way.